# aria label for list title, semantically correct?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a list of menu items links with a title describing the menu. This menu is floated left so to reduce mark up I have made the title part of the `ul` so it be be floated easily.

E.g

```
<ul>
    <li class="heading">My Title</li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Should I be doing anything special to separate the title? 
Add a [wai-aria](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles)? 
Is there any chance search engines could get confused?

It just doesn't seem semantically correct on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be more semantically correct to have the title separate from the list (being a list of links rather than a list of links and title). I don't know how this would affect search engines, however. But this shouldn't make styling any more difficult:

```
<div>
    <h4>My Title</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you were then wanting them displayed inline you could simply:

```
div h4, div ul, div ul li { display:inline-block; }
div ul { list-style-type:none; padding:0; }
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RNEgw/).

Answer (score 6):

According to the working draft [Using WAI-ARIA in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/), there are various roles that an `li` element may have, but `heading` is not among them. So no, you should not use an ARIA attribute to declare a list item as a heading.

So it would be more appropriate to make the heading a separate heading element before the list, as suggested by @JamesDonnelly, though you need to select the level of the heading according to the overall structure.

(Search engines probably couldn’t care less.)

(This isn’t really about semantics but about structure. Semantics is about meanings, and declaring an element as a heading does not describe its meaning, just its relationship with a structure, or its role.)